# Textisselectable is auto-scrolingl last word selected back on screen when opening app - Stack Overflow

Tags: java

I have a Textview with (android:textisselectable="true") attribute in it, when I click on a word in the textview it highlights like it should. The problem I am having is when I close and open the app, on opening the app again
the activity always auto-scrolls to the last word that was selected back on to the screen which is stopping the activity from saving at the last position it was at before closing the app. What I would like to do is when the user selects a word that word stays selected even if the app is closed so when the app is opened again that word stays selected even if it is not visible on screen.

```
public class Aman_Ruth_4_16 extends Nav_BaseActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_textview);
    displayDrawer();
    setFooterAds();


    TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);


    t1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Aman_Ruth_4_16)));


}

}




<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
  android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout_2"/>


 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/s1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Large_Text"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/highligttext"
            android:text=""


            android:textIsSelectable="true" />




   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```